# Can an object become flammable by being dipped in an arsenic lake?

Tags: chemistry, geology

I have a (water) lake on a planet that has a high concentration of arsenic in its crust. As a result, the lake has an extremely high concentration of aqueous arsenic.

From my research, it seems like arsenic powder is highly flammable.

The scenario I have in mind is that an non-flammable object is thoroughly soaked in the lake, removed and air-dried if necessary, and then is placed in contact with another, extremely hot object on the shore. The arsenic now coating the first object catches fire and burns off of the first object like alcohol.

The temperature and atmospheric composition on this planet are similar to Earth’s.

I am certainly no chemical engineer, so I have no idea if this makes sense. Could a naturally-occurring arsenic compound have this effect when drawn from water?

Comment: Seems like a question for a different stack exchange.

Comment: @KaffeeByte possibly, but since the lake is part of the ecosystem I am trying to build, there may be World-building concerns that I haven’t considered with it as opposed to just the chemistry of this specific reaction. I am willing to ask it elsewhere if necessary though.

Comment: Arsenic is not soluble in water. Whatever got dissolved in the waters of the lake was not arsenic but probably some sort of arsenic compound; if I could hazard a guess I would say arsenic trioxide, which is occasionally called white arsenic in detective novels set in the Victorian era, but that doesn't work because the question says "extremely high concentration" and arsenic trioxide solution concentration is max 2%. The point being that in order to say what happens to an object dipped in the lake then dried in the sun, we need to know what got dissolved in the water and in what concentration.

Comment: @AlexP shoot, sorry- edited too early I think. Should I ask a separate question about what compound I should use?

Comment: I have no idea. Chemistry is but a dim recollection of high school days, a long time ago. But I really don't remember being told that arsenic could be prepared by dissolving something in water and then evaporating the water -- it always seemed to involve doing something with realgar or other mineral involving the application of lots of heat.

Answer (score 4):

## No, it doesn't work the way you're thinking

The aqueous arsenic that would be found in a seawater is either Arsenic V or Arsenic III. These numbers represent the oxidation state of the ion. The flammability of powdered Arsenic that you mentioned is the oxidation of the elemental Arsenic. But the arsenic in the seawater is already oxidized, so it can't burn again (at least not easily).

This is a simplified view of the chemistry, but it does address the fundamental issue.

Comment: Perfect. Just to confirm, arsenic ions are also what’s present in freshwater due to fertilizers, correct?

Comment: Most of the time yes. There are always exceptions, but yes, most arsenic in these are going to be ions in solution.

Comment: It'll be arsenic ions, ions that *contain* arsenic (like arsenate), or organoarsenic compounds like cacodylic acid. At any rate, anything that could potentially produce a pyrophoric coating on drying, is unlikely to be found in large quantities in open-air lakes.